# replacing a character using str.charAt()

Tags: jquery, ajax, string

I am using AJAX and PHP to generate HTML, but I do not want there to be any 'Underscores' displayed. Therefore I am using a loop to sort through the AJAX results, through 'alert testing' I know that the correct char and corresponding "displayedText" value are being displayed, also that it is correctly identifying the 'underscore' characters. But when I attempt to replace them with "result.charAt(x) = ' ';" The loop blows up and fails to run.

Here is my script:

```
            $.ajax({                                                          
                  url: '/php/SubMenuBar.php',         
                  data: {
                          MainCategory: mainCategory,
                        },

                  success: function(result)
                 {
                        var displayedText = true;

                        for (var x = 0; x < result.length; x++)
                        {
                            var c = result.charAt(x);

                            alert( c + displayedText);

                            if (c == '<')
                            {
                                displayedText = false;  
                            }
                            else if (c == '>')
                            {
                                displayedText = true;   
                            }

                            if (displayedText && c == '_')
                            {   
                                alert('Found one');                             
                                result.charAt(x) = ' '; //SCRIPT BLOWS UP HERE
                                alert("'" + result.charAt(x) + "'"); //THIS ALERT NEVER FIRES AND THE LOOP EXITS
                            }
                        }

                        subMenuBar.html(result); 
                  }
                });
```

Comment: Granted I haven't studied this question in detail, but if you're just trying to strip out characters why not use `String.prototype.replace()`?

Comment: Do you only care about underscores in a particular place in the text (like the start, middle or end)? If not, you can just go a generic `.replace()` which is much easier.

Comment: You can't modify strings in Javascript. You have to return a new string that contains the modified version.

Comment: --Utkanos I am pretty new to JQuery, so I'm not familiar with that :P, --Ishan Chatterjee I am only trying to target underscores that will be displayed on the page, which is any underscore that is outside of a <tag>, therefore I trigger a boolean on < and >. --Barmar using result = result.substring ... ; I was able to replace the string.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I replaced

```
if (displayedText && c == '_')
                    {   
                        alert('Found one');                             
                        result.charAt(x) = ' '; //SCRIPT BLOWS UP HERE
                        alert("'" + result.charAt(x) + "'"); //THIS ALERT NEVER FIRES AND THE LOOP EXITS
                    }
```

With this:

```
if (displayedText && c == '_')
{   
    alert('Found one');
    result = result.substring(0,x) + ' ' + result.substring(x + 1, result.length);
    alert(result.charAt(x));
}
```

Using the substring of everything before the character i want to replace, the new character I want, and then everything after the character i want to replace through manipulation of substrings.